Problem with graphics in Ubuntu, on Intel Arc GPU
I'm new to Linux and encountering a couple of problems that I just can't seem to solve. I believe they're related because they either appear together or not at all. I've tried taking screenshots to capture the dots, but they don't show up. I don't think it's a hardware issue since everything worked fine in Windows when I was dual booting at first. I switched to Linux fully when I thought I had fixed the problem.
The problem:

Random black screens: My screen occasionally goes black for 1 to 5 seconds at seemingly random times. This seems to happen more frequently under medium to heavy load, but I'm not entirely sure.

Flickering white lines: There are flickering white lines across the screen, particularly at the top, which become more noticeable during these flickering episodes.

Random red and green dots: I see random red and green dots on my background. Their positions change when I move the cursor or interact with the screen, which i think suggests that they might be related to how the screen updates.


PC info:
System:
  Host: anton-HP-Spectre-x360 Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)

Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 Laptop
    14-eu0xxx v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8C15 v: 84.40 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.10 date: 04/10/2024

Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 59.3 Wh (90.3%) condition: 65.7/68.0 Wh (96.6%)

CPU:
  Info: 16-core (6-mt/10-st) model: Intel Core Ultra 7 155H bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 18 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 576 min/max: 400/4500:4800:3800:2500 cores: 1: 400
    2: 400 3: 400 4: 400 5: 400 6: 400 7: 4278 8: 400 9: 400 10: 400 11: 400
    12: 400 13: 400 14: 400 15: 400 16: 400 17: 400 18: 400 19: 400 20: 400
    21: 400 22: 400

Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Meteor Lake-P [Intel Arc Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 2880x1800~120Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: Mesa Intel Arc Graphics (MTL)

Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: intel-ipu6
  Device-2: Intel Meteor Lake-P HD Audio driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-45-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 7 AX1775 /AX1790 /BE20 /BE401/BE1750 2x2
    driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 4c:49:6c:41:84:62

Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 4C:49:6C:41:84:66 bt-v: 5.4

Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 22.3 GiB (2.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: KIOXIA model: N/A size: 953.87 GiB

Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 936.79 GiB used: 22.3 GiB (2.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1

Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img

Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 3564 fan-2: 3213

Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB note: est. available: 30.71 GiB used: 4.92 GiB (16.0%)
  Processes: 443 Uptime: 15m Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34

mode "2880x1800"
    geometry 2880 1800 2880 1800 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode

I found this semi-unknown device in the Software & Updates application. Could it be this? It doesn't seem to change anything.

